# Nodejs application using knex breaks after inserting few records into the Postgres database

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, observable, knex.js

My Nodejs application using knex breaks after inserting few records into the Postgres database with the following error:

**Unhandled rejection Error**

```
aborted at PendingOperation.abort (/mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/tarn/lib/PendingOperation.js:25:17)
at Promise.all.pendingAcquires.map.acquire (/mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/tarn/lib/Pool.js:190:23)
at Array.map (native)
at Promise.all.then.then (/mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/tarn/lib/Pool.js:189:34)
```

**From previous event:**

```
at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:335:34)
at /mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:191:41
```

**From previous event:**

```
at Transaction.acquireConnection (/mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:190:34)
at new Transaction (/mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:68:53)
at Client_PG.transaction (/mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:159:12)
at Function.transaction (/mnt/c/Users/*********/node_modules/knex/lib/util/make-knex.js:75:21)
```

**Here is the code where it breaks:**

```
const writeOrdersToDB$ = (order: Order): Observable<Order> => {
  const orderToInsert = cleanOrder(order);
  return Observable.fromPromise(knex.transaction((trx: Transaction) => trx('order')
    .insert(orderToInsert)
    .returning('*')));
};
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, add complete code to test it out. Probably your observable code is not doing what you are thinking it does and is leaking connections.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It solved my problem:

This works:

```js
finally(x => knex.destroy());
```

This does not work:

```js
finally(knex.destroy());
```

Comment: that is normal js syntax error : you want to pass `knex.destroy` to the `finally` call, not the result of calling `knex.destroy()`.
`finally(knex.destroy);`
would work as expected